# Call view.phtml template in custom layout

Tags: templates, magento, layout

I am new in magento i am getting issue while calling the `view.phtml` file in custom layout.

Folowing is my code which is i am including in cutom layout file but i am getting Fatal error
 `Fatal error: Call to a member function getMetaTitle() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\projects\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View.php on line 56`.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view')->setTemplate('catalog/product/view.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Please reply me for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the $this-> before getLayout() ? By the way you should use a loayout xml file and not force the creation of a block like that

Comment: Hi Bixi,
Thanks for your reply.
Can you able to give me the steps for this how can i got to build that one? It will be very helpful for me.

Thanks for your reply....again

Comment: Ok Thanks i will see on this.

Answer (score 2):

Your error occurs in the file `D:\wamp\www\projects\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View.php` on this line

```
$product = $this->getProduct();
$title = $product->getMetaTitle();
```

When you create a block you do not specify a product for which the block is created, and this is an important and required parameter.

Function to get the product :

```
public function getProduct()
{
      if (!Mage::registry('product') && $this->getProductId()) 
      {
          $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId());
          Mage::register('product', $product);
      }
        return Mage::registry('product');
 }
```

Do you actually have one option how to fix this problem, but it is not quite beautiful, but working.

```
 <?php
    Mage::register('product',Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(YOUR_PRODUCT_ID));
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view')->setTemplate('catalog/product/view.phtml')->toHtml();
    Mage::unregister('product');
 ?>
```

This decision **can not** be used on the product page.

Comment: Hi Dzmitry,
Thanks for your reply... It'w working fine but not getting the full view just like view.phtml some are missing like Product price, Add to cart functionality,Product image. Can you please tell me how to go for that one?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't instantiate a Block like that.

Take a look at the standard product page to understand how it works :

You have a controller named catalog/product/view wich is defined in the Mage_Catalog_ProductController class

This controller is linked to a Layout update handle defined in the catalog.xml file in app/design/package/theme/layout/catalog.xml

In this layout file, you'll see that the block catalog/product_view is declared with a few children :

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    [...]
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
                <label>Alert Urls</label>
            </block>
            [...]
```

This this the part you're missing by instantiate it manually.

You must adapt/understand the layout in catalog.xml for your needs

Good luck